# JSQMessages send media

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Im building a small chat app using `JSQMessages`, and trying to send images from photo library or camera.

I got to the point where I saved the image to parse backend but I cannot display it on screen. I found few solutions but they were in obj-C, I tried to swift-fy but it failed.

I have extra column in parse "images" next to "message".

Here is what I tried:

```
var message = messages[indexPath.row]
if message != "" {
  return messages[indexPath.row]
} else if message?.isMediaMessage == true {
  let mediaItem:JSQMessageMediaData = message!.media
  if (mediaItem.isKindOfClass(JSQPhotoMediaItem)) {
    var photoItem: JSQPhotoMediaItem = mediaItem as! JSQPhotoMediaItem
    var image: UIImage = photoItem.image
    print("yay")
  }
}
return messages[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually setting the message content to the photo that you have saved on the backend. You have a `var image: UIImage = photoItem.image` that just saves it to a variable not to the message content that is being displayed. Also this does evaluate `if (mediaItem.isKindOfClass(JSQPhotoMediaItem)) {
    var photoItem: JSQPhotoMediaItem = mediaItem as! JSQPhotoMediaItem`

so if set your message.media = (data from parse) it should show up.

Comment: Thanks for the info. as i mentioned, thats what i have tried. i know its not working :( having difficulties understanding you though. as you said.(mediaItem.isKindOfClass(JSQPhotoMediaItem)) {
    var photoItem: JSQPhotoMediaItem = mediaItem as! JSQPhotoMediaItem part. am i on the write track? beside displaying the picture on UIImage?

Comment: I would say ya your on the right track but wont know till your displaying in message bubbles.